# SimpleXMLElement in foreach loop keeps nesting inside PHP

Tags: php, xml

Im using SimpleXMLElement as follows:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xml></xml>');
$xml->addChild('tests');
```

Then im trying to add individual tests inside of the above  like so:

```
foreach($tests as $test){

    $node1 = $xml->tests->addChild('test');
    $node1->addAttribute('name', $test[0]);
    $node1->addAttribute('example', $test[1]);

    $subnode1 = $node1->addChild('header');
    $subnode1->addAttribute('example', 'example');
}

echo $xml->asXML();
```

I want the finished output to look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <tests>
        <test name="test name" example="example">
            <header example="example"></header>
        </test>
        <test name="test name" example="example">
            <header example="example"></header>
        </test>
    </tests>
</xml>
```

But instead i'm getting something more like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <tests>
        <test name="test name" example="example">
            <header example="example">
                <test name="test name" example="example">
                    <header example="example">
                        <test name="test name" example="example">
                            <header example="example"></header>
                        </test>
                    </header>
                </test>
            </header>
        </test>
    </tests>
</xml>
```

Any advice as to what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: What does your `$tests` input array look like? That is probably where your issue lies. With a simple flat array like `$tests = ['testone','testtwo'];` your code (or something almost like it) produces the output you wanted.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => example [1] => example [2] => example [3] => example ) [1] => Array ( [0] => example [1] => example [2] => example [3] => example ) multidimensional array

Comment: Ok, it does seem to work as you posted it, see https://3v4l.org/04ClJ. The fact that you are seeing nesting suggests there could be more to your code, like you are involving objects or making other variable assignments with SimpleXML nodes that would cause references to be used when not expected.

Comment: the code you see above is what i'm working with, no objects or other variable assignments at all. Cannot understand why this is not working

Comment: If you change the data in the array, do you see that change in the output? In other words, are you _sure_ you're executing this exact code? I don't see anything wrong with it either. I think there is more code influencing behavior, or different code altogether, or you've run into some obscure bug that might be related to the exact versions and builds of your system. I'd triple check the first options before assuming it's the latter.